# Firebase Web SDK 3.x ServerValue timestamp?

Tags: javascript, firebase, timestamp, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to figure out the alternative to `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` from SDK v 2.x in SDK v3.x

Does anyone know what's the new way to get firebase server timestamp in the Web SDK?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue.html#fields. What language are you using?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry forgot to mention I am using Web (Javascript) SDK. Just updated details.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#.ServerValue and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps. If you're having problems getting that working, show what you've tried please.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thats great, thanks mate it worked just fine.

Answer (score 12):

It is now  firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Comment: Actual answer answers are better for future readers than comments! This answer, because it's correct, deserves upvotes <3

Comment: Agreed, comments should be for asking for clarification. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my answer, with the import added:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// ...

firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```